# WP Query order posts not working

Tags: wp-query, sort

Hello I have custom wp query

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'marketing_en',
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
     'taxonomy' => 'custom_post_type', 
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => array(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ar' ? 'tool-ar' : 'tool'),
      ),),);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

And i need to order posts by oldest post or by number in post "see image"

I tried to add 'orderby' to the array but it is not working with me. i want for ex the title '01 concepts' to be the first in the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by title in ascending order (alphabetical order), you can use `orderby` => `title` and `order` => `ASC`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'marketing_en',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom_post_type', 
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ar' ? 'tool-ar' : 'tool'),
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Make sure you have the correct values in the `post_type` and `taxonomy` fields. The value of `post_type` should be the custom post type you are querying and the taxonomy should be the correct taxonomy associated with your posts.

Comment: Working! thank you a lot